# What encoding do strings found in the Mach-O __DATA segment, __cfstring section use?

Tags: iphone, string, macos, encoding, mach-o

I'm wondering how to properly read strings from a specific section of a Mach-O binary. (This is a binary for iOS.)

I'm curious about the strings found in the `__DATA` segment, `__cfstring` section. These sections appear to contain arrays of simple structures:

```
NSConstantString
{
    Class class;
    const char *string;
    int length;
}
```

The question comes down to: how do you decide the encoding of the `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's described in the source of `CFString` available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFString.c). It's either in ASCII or UTF16 (in the processor endian-ness.) 
Also see the source code of `clang`, available [here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGObjCMac.cpp). Look for `GenerateConstantString`. Constant strings are eventually generated by [this piece of code](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp), look for `GetAddrOfConstantCFString`.  The source code says that the constant CFString is of the format

```
  struct __builtin_CFString {
     const int *isa; // point to __CFConstantStringClassReference
     int flags;
     const char *str;
     long length;
 };
```

(at least on OS X, I'm not sure about iOS.) `flags` tells you whether it's ASCII or UTF16.